# Symptoms of thread leak

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads, memory-leaks

I have a C++ application that isn't calling `pthread_join` and has O(time running) threads.  My question is - how would this affect the health of the server task?  Is there a fixed number of threads a C++ task can hold before it crashes or fails to start new threads?  Will this manifest as an error code in `pthread_create`?  Does it just leak memory or will it slow down processing time of the rest of the applications?

The threads are finishing (top level function is returning), just not being `pthread_join`'ed.

Comment: If nothing else, there's a fundamental limit of `2^(8*sizeof(pthread_t))` threads by a simple counting argument...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The POSIX manual says [`pthread_create`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_create.html) can return `EAGAIN`:

> The system lacked the necessary resources to create another thread, or
>   **the system-imposed limit on the total number of threads in a process
>   {`PTHREAD_THREADS_MAX`} would be exceeded**.

A simple fix would be to mark the threads detached using [`pthread_detach`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_detach.html) or using an attribute and `pthread_attr_setdetachstate`. Then when they die they're just collected.

Comment: interesting but this is all I find on /usr/include on a grep:

`/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/local_lim.h:#undef PTHREAD_THREADS_MAX`